# "An entry with the same key already exists" exception in sortedlist entry in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sortedlist

Check the below function I'm getting an exception when running the program like

> "An entry with the same key already exists".

Inside the if condition. but i think there is no chance for the same key exception. Please help me to find the solution.

```
int loop=0;
string a;
string b;
string c;
string d;
string e;
string f; 

public void function()
{
   loop++;
   int i = -1;
   while(i>0)
   {
        string[] strDataArray = new string[]  {a,b,c,d,e,f};
        SortedList<decimal, string[]> slData = new SortedList<decimal, string[]>();

        slData = dicData[dicIP[socCurrentSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()]];
        if (!slData.ContainsKey(ConvertToDecimal(0013b84b83a6) + loop))
                        slData.Add(ConvertToDecimal(0013b84b83a6) + loop, strDataArray);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Firstly.. it would help to see your **actual** code. At best, we can only make guesses with this. Secondly, if your `loop` variable is outside the loop.. it isn't being incremented, thereby making duplicate entries into the sorted list..

Comment: I agree with @SimonWhitehead.  The code above cannot be your actual code.  That's just a mess.

Comment: ya you are right. but i think i clearly explained my problem..

Comment: You may think you clearly explained your problem, but everyone else seems to disagree.  The only answer as of this writing explains why your sample code *could not possibly throw the exception you are trying to diagnose*.  If the sample code does not demonstrate your problem, how are we supposed to help you solve that problem?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.. i ll completely explain the code..

Answer (score 1):

something is wrong with your loop:

1. i is equal to -1, it wouldn't even enter your loop
2. loop variable is never updated inside your loop